# Optional parameter in .NET Core Web API route template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
[HttpGet("{pageNumber}{pageSize?}{filter?}{sortOrder?}", Name = "GetEntriesPaged")]
public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetEntriesPaged(
    int pageNumber, int pageSize = 10, string filter = "", string sortOrder = "desc") {
```

Run-time exception:

> System.ArgumentException: An optional parameter must be at the end of
>   the segment. In the segment
>   '{pageNumber}{pageSize?}{filter?}{sortOrder?}', optional parameter
>   'pageSize' is followed by 'filter'. Parameter name: routeTemplate

What is the point? I have an optional parameter at the end of the segment, as asked....

PS. The more complete code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll() {
    var result = _db.Entries.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
    return result;
}

[HttpGet("{pageNumber}{pageSize?}{filter?}{sortOrder?}", Name = "GetEntriesPaged")]
public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetEntriesPaged(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10, string filter = "", string sortOrder = "desc") {
    int take = pageSize;
    int skip = ((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
    IQueryable<Entry> result;

    if (sortOrder == "asc") {
        result = _db.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
    }
    else {
        result = _db.Entries.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
    }

    return result.Skip(skip).Take(take).Where(x => x.Origin.Contains(filter)).ToList();
}

[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetEntry")]
public ActionResult<Entry> GetById(long id) {
    var item = _db.Entries.Find(id);
    if (item == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return item;
}
```

I need for `/entries` the `GetAll()` method to be used, but with `/esntries?pageNumber=3` the `GetEntriesPaged(...)` one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you don't. `sortOrder` is at the end, but `pageSize` and `filter` are not. In short, you cannot have multiple optional parameters like this. It creates too many combinations of routes, which would render it impossible to determine how to route the request or what particular route params to fill. For example, what if you fill in `pageSize` and `sortOrder` but not `filter`? How is ASP.NET Core supposed to know that what you supplied for `sortOrder` is not actually meant for `filter`?

FWIW, you also need slashes between these route params. Otherwise, there's no way to know where one ends and the next begins. For example, is a route like `/111` saying page one with a size of 11, page 11 with a size of 1, or page 111, and no size set? That still doesn't help you with having them all be optional though.

If you need multiple optional things in the URL, it's best to just use the query string to supply them.

**UPDATE**

You don't need and really shouldn't have multiple actions for paged or not. There's too much common functionality and the difference is too slight. The typical formula is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int? page = null, int pageSize = 10)
{
    var query = _context.Foos;
    if (page.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }

    return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: I understand the point, thank you for the explanation. However I also meant, the exception message is confusing. I DO have an optional parameter at the end. They should say something about the ONLY optional parameter, to be less confusing?! PS. What would be your suggestion to fix the problem?

Comment: Here, use the query string instead of the route - at least for some of the optional params. You can't have them all in the route itself and still keep them optional.

Comment: Simply pass the values in the query string, i.e. ?pageSize=10

Comment: I need to say "once you have pageNumber => use this function", maybe just `{pageNumber}` is enough? But I have already `[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetEntry")]`

Comment: Yes. The route is how it maps a URL to a particular action. You can send all kinds of other data along for the ride, which doesn't necessarily need to be part of the route itself.

Comment: will it differentiate from `HttpGet("{id}"` and `HttpGet("{pageNumber}"`?

Comment: Not unless there's a type different. For example, on the off chance that `id` was a GUID, then you could add a constraint to that route: `{id:guid}` and one to your page route: `{page:int}`. Then, it can tell the difference. However, if they're both ints, you're out of luck.

Comment: id is long, the pageNumber is an int

Comment: FWIW, page number shouldn't really be part of your route anyways. The URI defines a unique resource. For something like `/foos`, that's the collection of all "foos", while `/foos/1` implies a specific "foo". The resource you're paging would be `/foos` in this example, so it's more semantic to have `/foos?page=2`.

Comment: That's not enough of a difference. Either can be interpreted as the other. The only issue would be if there's an id that overflows the int on the page route, but that wouldn't occur until the action was already resolved, so it can't be used to determine which route to actually hit.

Comment: Not necessarily. The same action can and should serve both. There's functionally no difference between the two other than one will return a subset of the other. That means all other functionality would be duplicated. See my update above.

Comment: the problem is the default `pageSize` as I take 10 by default, it returns only 10 results, not all...when I have the `pageNumber`, I should use 10 as *pageSize*, but when not, I need to return all of them

Comment: The code in my update already accounts for that. The initial query is not paged. If the page number isn't passed, it never is.

Comment: A simple rule of thumb to consider.  Use route params to *uniquely identify* a resource or collection of resources.  Anything else is optional and belongs in the query string.